# control-m migrate from dev to prod

Tags: control-m

I am new in Control-M 8.0, could someone help me out?
I developed 3 new jobs a1,a2,a3 in DEV folder xyz, and I want to move a1,a2,a3 to PROD folder xyz. Currently there are b1,b2 in PROD xzy folder. 
My questions are:

1. how to deploy to PROD from DEV? Is the below correct?

   1. I export a1,a2,a3 from DEV xzy folder to a.xml file.
   2. I export b1,b2 from PROD xyz folder to b.xml.
   3. open a.xml and b.xml.
   4. copy the content of a.xml and paste to into bottom of b.xml and save as bb.xml.
   5. send bb.xml to product support team to import to PROD
2. in bb.xml. do I need to change hostname, creation_user, version_host of DEV to PROD hostname, creation_user, version_host? Will these be changed automatically when support team deploy bb.xml?
3. Do we have to make JOBISN unique? In bb.xml, job a1 and job b1 have the same JOBISN, do I have to change JOBISN of a1 to any other value that is not same as JOBISN of b1?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the two folders in the same "Workspace" then copy those jobs from one table to the other one. Change the values you need as hostname, user, etc...
2. Control-8 does not do that. Control-M 9.0.18 does it. You should consider upgrade your Control-M.